# Get code string in Android

Tags: android

Ex: I have a project with UI contains a button..
Activity:

```
package android.tuanshaker.myproject.com;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyProjectActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

And file main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to display code and xml of my project by textview..How do i can to get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the xml, js code files to `res/raw`. Use [Context.getResources().openRawResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29) to read them.

In addition, you can use [jHighlight](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFEQFjAA&url=http://www.ohloh.net/p/jhighlight&ei=DfHAT7bSHOyfiAf5l6iJCg&usg=AFQjCNEdk_0YIgS6V8iGfEsk5YlE_n6VuA) to [format those source codes (in a web view)](http://code.google.com/p/android-binding/source/browse/trunk/MarkupDemoV30/src/gueei/binding/markupDemov30/widget/CodeView.java).